# How can I provide an answer to a locked question that would benefit from a newer perspective?

Tags: support, answers, locked-posts

I want to upgrade Angular CLI on my machine and I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version) about doing so. Despite the rather old answers which are partially obsolete (e.g. the initial CLI package was renamed in the meantime), it has been locked to prevent further answers with the following reason:

> This question's answers are a community effort. **Edit existing answers
> to improve this post.** It is not currently accepting new answers or
> interactions.

However, I see no community wiki post.

I would like to add an answer from a more modern perspective (Angular 8 -> 9 / 10), but I do not want to mess with anyone's answer. How should I proceed?

**Question:** How can I provide an answer to a locked question that would benefit from a newer perspective?

Comment: That's odd. The wiki lock often goes together with making everything a wiki. You have sufficient rep to edit that answer without it being a wiki, though, so I'd just do that, not answering here because the true answer would explain why this isn't a wiki.

Comment: In that specific case, were you expecting something beyond `npm i -g <package>@latest`? Upgrading Angular *within* a project is already covered, they have their own site for it: https://update.angular.io/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I have managed to upgrade to the latest major (stable) without explicit latest. Also, I have noticed that `upgrade` was an answer, but it only gets you to the latest within the existing major version. Yes, I can edit the first answer although it seems to address really old CLI versions and what I have noticed works for latest versions.